# How can i implement a SlidingDrawer with a ListView inside on Android API Level 10?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-listview, slidingdrawer

I have been messing with android for quite awhile, and i have already built user interfaces using the `DrawerLayout` from Android Support Library v4.

My college teacher forced us to use API Level 10 for building our apps for this discipline, so that's what im doing.

I am trying to build a SlidingDrawer that has a ListView Inside, but i can't find the right way to do it. The following code leads to two errors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/details"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SlidingDrawer
          android:id="@+id/slidingDrawerShowMore"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:topOffset="132dip"
          android:handle="@+id/handle"
          android:content="@+id/handle">

        <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"             
         android:layout_width="88dip"
         android:layout_height="44dip" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

Error Messages:

```
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

and

```
Exception raised during rendering: The content attribute is must refer to an existing child.
```

(This one is raised after i change the content value of the drawer to @+id/content)

Here is the result i am looking forward to achieve.

[Navigation Drawer Component](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Any ideas of how can i have it solved ?

I have this UI running perfectly on API 17, with a custom ListAdapter on the ListView on the DrawerLayout ( from android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout), but it does not work on lower API levels.

Answer (score 1):

You are using NavigationDrawer which uses [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) Component in android. This will work on only 3.0 and above. So you need to remove ActionBar code in your app and try you own header code.

Otherwise change the code of actionbar to [ActionBarCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) which is a library used to handle actionbar in lower versions and implementation is very easy just follow the url